# typescript - group and sum array of objects - problem with casting string to array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the code -

Interface -

```
interface IWEXInterface {
  readonly Date?: string;
  "Exec Qty"?: string;
  readonly Expiry?: string;
}
```

Data -

```
let data: IWEXInterface[] = [
        {
          Date: "8/30/2021",
          "Exec Qty": "13",
          Expiry: "17/09/2021",
        },
        {
          Date: "8/30/2021",
          "Exec Qty": "15",
          Expiry: "17/09/2021",
        },
        {
          Date: "8/30/2021",
          "Exec Qty": "13",
          Expiry: "17/09/2021",
        },
      ];
```

Sum and group the objects -

```
      const sums = [
        ...data
          .reduce((map, item) => {
            const { Date: key, "Exec Qty": qty } = item;
            const prev: IWEXInterface = map.get(key);

            if (prev) {
              prev["Exec Qty"]! += Number(qty);
            } else {
              map.set(key, Object.assign({}, item));
            }

            return map;
          }, new Map())
          .values(),
      ];

      console.log(sums);
```

The output -

```
[ { Date: '8/30/2021', 'Exec Qty': '131513', Expiry: '17/09/2021' } ]
```

How can I cast the string to number.

Wanted output -

```
 [ { Date: '8/30/2021', 'Exec Qty': 41, Expiry: '17/09/2021' } ]
```

.............................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

try to replace your code with this one, it will return a string but the right one.

```
     if (prev) {         
    prev["Exec Qty"]! = (Number(prev["Exec Qty"])+ Number(qty)).toString()
            } else {
              map.set(key, Object.assign({}, item));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast `prev["Exec Qty"]` to number:

```
prev["Exec Qty"] = String(Number(prev["Exec Qty"]!) + Number(qty));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not use the `+=` shorthand?

```
prev["Exec Qty"] = Number(prev["Exec Qty"]) + Number(qty);
```